# Format a numeric field as text with fixed pattern sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a numeric field (field1) that has numeric values 1.2, 23.72, 14.02 etc.
I need to present this as a fixed text field format 13 characters as 000000000.000 e.g. 23.72 must display 000000023.720 (9 digits with 3 decimals)Server 2008
What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: "What is the best way to do this?" - put your presentation concerns in a component that deals with formatting (e.g. an application or a report builder) rather than shoving it down into the database server where it doesn't really belong?

Comment: In C#, the best way would be `string.Format("{0:000000000.000}", decimalVariable)`.  Add a tag for the application language you are using since SQL is never the best place to format data for presentation purposes.

Comment: Not mentioning that hard-coding the decimal separator char can quickly create an unfixable mess when applied to a culture in which a different symbol is used for that same purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(ColumnName, '000000000.000') FROM TableName
```

I'm not saying this is the best way, as the final presentation layer (your webpage) might still render it as a numeric value that will follow the format defined on that layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FORMAT(@input, '000000000.000')` but that won't give you intended output for longer numbers. 
You can make your own function which pads zeros ahead and otherwise stops your execution in case of longer numbers.

```
DECLARE @input NUMERIC(20,7);
DECLARE @number NUMERIC(12,3);
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(13)

SET @input = 123620;
SET @number = CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,3), @input)

SET @output = CONVERT(CHAR(13), @number)
SET @output = REPLICATE('0', 10 - CHARINDEX('.',@output)) + @output
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I just need to present the data in SQL report writer 2008 .. I don't need to create a field

Comment: Okay, just combine these three as single statement, assuming name of your column is NumberCol, use this: `REPLICATE('0', 10 - CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(CHAR(13), CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,3), NumberCol)))) + CONVERT(CHAR(13), CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,3), NumberCol))`

Comment: Almost but it seems to be putting 8 spaces on the end of the field ?

Comment: Can you tell me the test case for which it is doing like the way you mentioned?

Comment: All values in the numeric field 23.2 ,, 6.7 etc. Not important as I have added a LEFT function to only produce the 13 chars I require.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @i float=23.72
declare @j decimal(18,3)=@i
select @j
select replicate('0',13-len(@j))+cast(@j as varchar)
```

and tell that for which data it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',12) + CAST('23.72' AS VARCHAR(10)),12) + REPLICATE('0',3),13)
```

output

> 000000023.720